# Python -> Labels cant be shown to Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame

Labels can't be shown into the leftFrame. I'm quite new to Python GUI. My code kinda goes like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mainFrame = Frame(root, width=700, height=500)
mainFrame.pack()

leftFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bg="#c2c3c4")
leftFrame.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.34, anchor=W)

label1 = Label(leftFrame, text="Label1")
label2 = Label(leftFrame, text="Label2")

label1.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W, pady=(20, 0))
label2.grid(columnspan=3, sticky=W, pady=(5, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

---

Comment: Quite likely there is an issue because you have a mix of `pack`, `place` and `grid`. Try to stick to one geometry manager.

Comment: @StevenSummers: no, the problem isn't because `pack`, `place` and `grid` are mixed together. It's simply that the OP is using `place` incorrectly. I think the best practice is to use `grid` and `pack` together in an application, just be aware you can't use them both for widgets that have the same parent.

Comment: Ah Okay, I thought it was best to avoid mixing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't see the labels because they are off the screen. `leftFrame` has an anchor of `W`, which means that the vertical center of `leftFrame` is at 0,0.  In other words, half of the frame is above the visible portion of the window.

A quick fix to prove this out is to use an anchor of `NW` instead of `W`, which will cause the upper-left corner of the frame to be at the upper-left corner of its parent.

However, I strongly encourage you to *not* use `place` at all. It has its uses, but really should rarely be used. You end up having to do a lot of work yourself, and the result is usually not very responsive to changes in fonts, resolutions, or window sizes.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the response. :D